# Why do people add `true` before incrementing or decrementing a variable in sh?

Tags: shell

I have a script which contains the `true $(( var-- ))` statement inside a while loop what does this mean? It could be simply `$(( var-- ))` without "**true**". But why in this way? What is the significance of **true** in that?

Comment: The more idiomatic variant is `: $(( var-- ))`, though it means the exact same thing (`:` and `true` are typically implemented as two different names for the same function in the builtin table). Likewise for `: "${varname:=default value}"`, vs `true "${varname:=default value}"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To complement [λuser's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39832081/45375):

The `true` in `true $(( var-- ))` is **a way to perform a variable assignment without causing (additional) side effects**:

- An **arithmetic expansion - `$(( ... ))`** - expands to (is replaced with) the *result* of the calculation/assignment.
- **Using an arithmetic expansion as a *stand-alone statement* causes the shell to interpret its result as a *command to execute*,** as user λuser notes - which is usually undesired.
- **By passing an arithmetic expansion as an *argument* to `true`, its result is effectively *ignored***, because `true` ignores any arguments you pass to it.

However:

- `--` and `++` aren't POSIX-compliant, as λuser points out.
- The preferred way to apply the expand-but-ignore-all-arguments trick is to use `:` rather than `true`; `:` is the [null utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/colon.html), whose express purpose is to expand, but otherwise ignore its arguments, while always setting the exit code to `0`.

Thus, to remain **POSIX-compliant**<sup>[1]</sup> (when used in a script targeting `/bin/sh`), you should use:

```
: $(( var-=1 ))
```

---

However, **if you can assume** **`bash`**, **`ksh`**, or **`zsh`**, you can use `--`, and also simply omit the `$` to get an arithmetic *evaluation* that does *not* expand to anything:

```
(( var-- ))
```

Or, to ensure exit code `0` (the exit code usually doesn't matter in the *body* of a loop):

```
: (( var-- ))
```

Note that `(( ... ))` sets its exit code to `1` if the calculation results in `0`, and to `0` for any nonzero result, which allows direct use in conditionals (`if (( ... )); then ...`), as an arithmetic/Boolean alternative to `[ ... ]` / `[[ ... ]]` conditionals.

---

<sup>[1] Note that POSIX does allow for `--` and even `(( ... ))`, but only as *optional extensions*, so you cannot assume their presence on all platforms.</sup>

Comment: "Suppressing standard output" might not be the right term. We're not stopping the resulting numeric value from being printed on the console; we're stopping it from being executed as a command. (Being an arithmetic expansion, we're not even behaving as a command substitution would and capturing a subprocess's stdout).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Good point, thanks. Hope my revision is an improvement.

Comment: LGTM. A little heavy on the bolding, but that's well into bikeshedding territory.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy **:)**

Answer (score 4):

`$var--` doesn't decrement in normal shell.
To do mathematical operations, one has to [enclose it with `$(())`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04) (and btw `--` is not in regular POSIX shell).

However, this is an expression, so, after computation, it returns an output (the result of expression) which is then interpreted in the context of a command. If your line contains just `$((var--))`, it will try to evaluate the result as a command, e.g. as if your line contained just the number 42. The shell will probably complain it cannot find a command named `42`.

The `true` command is expected to exist and discard its arguments.

Comment: Nice explanation. Never thought about that.

Comment: "Returns" might not be the best terminology to use -- usually in shell that word is used to refer to exit status, whereas what we care about here is expansion results.